# I'm trying to store 2 user inputs (doubles) inisde a local array. I don't know the Syntax

Tags: java, arrays

> Instruction for the method:
> readMarks(): accepts Scanner object, return nothing. Reads number of courses, and then reads marks of all courses and stored them in a local array.

> I just need the syntax to store all the values inside the array and eventually use that array somewhere else. Is there a way to do that?

```
import java.util.Scanner;   

public class Student extends Person{
    private int studentNumber;
    private String programName;
    private double gpa;
    private double baseFees;
    private double maxMarks = 100;
    private double maxGPA = 4;

    public Student(int studentNumber, String programName, double gpa,
            double baseFees, String fName, String lName, String mail, long pNumber, double maxMarks, double maxGPA) {
        super(fName, lName, mail, pNumber);
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
        this.programName = programName;
        this.gpa = gpa;
        this.baseFees = baseFees;
        this.maxGPA = maxGPA;
        this.maxMarks = maxMarks;
    }
    
    public void readInfo(Scanner input) {
        System.out.println("Enter first Name: ");
        String  fName = input.next();
    
        System.out.println("Enter last name: ");
        String lName = input.next();
    
        System.out.println("Enter email: ");
        String mail = input.next();
    
        System.out.println("Enter phone number: ");
        long pNumber = input.nextLong();    
    
        System.out.println("Enter GPA: ");
        double gpa = input.nextDouble();
    
        System.out.println("Enter baseFees: ");
        double baseFees = input.nextDouble();   
    
        readMarks(input);
    }
    
    public void readMarks(Scanner  input) {
        System.out.println("Enter number of courses: ");
        double numberOfCourses = input.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.println("Enter marks: ");
        double courseMarks = input.nextDouble();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Problably
`double[] marks = new double[numberOfCourses];`. Where numberOfCourses has to be int not double. Then create variable index to store mark and read marks.

I don't follow if there is one mark per course or multiple. Implementation differ for each approach.

Comment: Has your course covered how to create/add values to an array?

Comment: No. I think i can look it up online

Comment: Yes, also look for examples of `scopes`. You will _probably_ need an array outside of the scope of the `readMarks` method.

Comment: @JettoMartínez the specification of the task clearly asks for the creation of a local array.

Comment: It does, is just that `readInfo()` within `Student` is a bit odd, which tells me that the class might be refactored in the future. Nevertheless you are correct, it should matter only if there is a requirement about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of courses should be `int`, no need to support fractions for it. And then you will need to create a `double` array and fill the values:

```
public void readMarks(Scanner  input) {
    System.out.println("Enter number of courses: ");
    int numberOfCourses = input.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Enter marks: ");
    double[] courseMarks = new double[numberOfCourses];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCourses; i++) {
        courseMarks[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }
    // Now you have an array, do something with it, but note, it's local
}
```